# Annotate fraction with changing value in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to combine fraction with value calculated elsewhere. I tried to combine it with `expression` and `paste` but didn't work. any suggestions please?

```
library(ggplot2)

Changing_Value <- 150

  ggplot(data=data.frame(x=0,y=0))+

  annotate('text', x = 0, y = 0, 
           label = "P^{frac(-1,K)}== Changing_Value ",parse = TRUE,size=7)
```

Comment: this? `paste("P^{frac(-1,K)}== ",Changing_Value)`

Comment: Thanks. I tried this way but somehow wasn't working. Maybe I need coffee :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf`. See the help file to see what other options are besides `%d`.

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0, y = 0)) +
  annotate("text", x = 0, y = 0, 
           label = sprintf("P^{frac(-1,K)}== %d", Changing_Value), 
           parse = TRUE, size = 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `paste` to generate the string:

```r
library(ggplot2)

Changing_Value <- 150

  ggplot(data=data.frame(x=0,y=0))+

  annotate('text', x = 0, y = 0, 
           label = paste("P^{frac(-1,K)}==",Changing_Value),parse = TRUE,size=7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `glue`

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0, y = 0)) +
  annotate("text", x = 0, y = 0, 
           label = glue::glue("P^frac(-1,K)=={Changing_Value}"), 
           parse = TRUE, size = 7)
```